# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmosquitto

Tags: c, build

I am trying to build an example code which uses libmosquitto. When i try to compile, it shows undefined reference.

```
→ gcc publish_data.o -o publish_data   
publish_data.o: In function `main':
publish_data.c:(.text+0x20c): undefined reference to `mosquitto_lib_init'
publish_data.c:(.text+0x22c): undefined reference to `mosquitto_lib_version'
publish_data.c:(.text+0x2b8): undefined reference to `mosquitto_new'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then i tried to link it manually with -L\path\ -lmosquitto. But the result is as below. I do not understand how to resolve this issue.

```
gcc publish_data.o -o publish_data -L/home/chinmaya/WorkSpace/Build_PayLoad/AWS-Build/PlatformSDK/Yukon/Release -lmosquitto     
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/chinmaya/WorkSpace/Build_PayLoad/AWS-Build/PlatformSDK/Yukon/Release/libmosquitto.so when searching for -lmosquitto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmosquitto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Would anyone please help me in understand the issue or what i have missed over here ?

Comment: "`skipping incompatible`" ask the question: for which platform do you compile (x86, arm, 32/64 bits...) what is the target of the compiled `libmosquitto.so`?

Comment: @hardillb Thank you for your response. I am compiling for x86_64. I am not sure about the target of the compiled libmosquitto.so as it is already provided with the controller package. Can you suggest me a way to check for the same ?